# Is GCM will work on Java SDK 1.4 or it required higher level of Java SDK

Tags: android

I am an Android developer and implementing GCM push notification in my app for that i am having one server which is built using Java 1.4 SDK, push notification is giving error. i am suspecting that it is due to Java 1.4 SDK.

Comment: I don't think that Android current SDK is allowing you to develop on 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requirements
For the web server:

- Ant 1.8 (it might work with earlier versions, but it's not guaranteed).
- One of the following:

  - A running web server compatible with Servlets API version 2.5, such as Tomcat 6 or Jetty, or
  - Java App Engine SDK version 1.6 or later.
- A Google account registered to use GCM.
- The API key for that account.

[From GCM guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html)